Take highlighted cells and move them to the bottom of the list, then tidy the list. Exception: Range not found
I am trying to Take highlighted cells and move them to the bottom of the list, then tidy the list. This is what I have so far.
function duplicateAndOrganizeActiveSheet() {
// Duplicate the sheet
  var mySS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var duplicateSheet = mySS.duplicateActiveSheet();

// Change the name of the new sheet.
  duplicateSheet.setName(duplicateSheet.getSheetId());
  duplicateSheet.setTabColor(null);

// Get the array of background color in each cell for that range
  var range = duplicateSheet.getRange('A2:A')
  var bkg = range.getBackgrounds();

// Take highlighted cells and move them to the bottom of the list, then tidy the list
  // iterate over rows 
  for(var i=0;i<bkg.length;i++){
    // iterate over columns
    for(var j=0;j<bkg[i].length;j++){
    // if the specific cell at row i and column j is mid yellow '#ffd966'
      var results = [[],[]]
      if(bkg[i][j]==='#ffd966') results.push([i],[j])
        // Move matching cells to the bottom of the list
        var end_list = duplicateSheet.getRange('A:A').getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN)
        var destination = duplicateSheet.getRange(end_list +':A')
        destination.setValues(results)
    }
  }

// trim blank cells from top of list
  var range2 = duplicateSheet.getRange('E2:E'+duplicateSheet.getLastRow())      // get a range start from row 2
  var data = range2.getValues().filter(String);                                 // get a data and remove empty elements
  range2.clearContent().offset(0,0,data.length).setValues(data);                // put the data back on the sheet

Everything out side of my loop sequence works as expected, I just don't have enough experience to get the output working.
I started with
var results = [] if(bkg[i][j]==='#ffd966') results.push(i,j)
then googled the error message, then tried again, then googled the next error message, etc...
my current error message is
Exception: Range not found on line 21 (results.push)

Tried this change
 // Move matching cells to the bottom of the list         var end_list = duplicateSheet.getRange('A:A').getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN)       /*  var destination = duplicateSheet.getRange(end_list +':A')         destination.setValues(results)*/         end_list.setValues(results)     }   }
Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 4 but the range has 1.

This is the solution one of my Works friends came up with.
function transferData() {
  // Step 1: Count cells that are not empty in range C2 - C8
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Baylands DM Schedual");
  var range = sourceSheet.getRange("C2:C8");
  var values = range.getValues();
  var count = values.reduce(function(acc, val) {
    if (val[0] !== "") {
      return acc + 1;
    } else {
      return acc;
    }
  }, 0);

  // Step 2: Go to sheet called history and insert number of rows equal to count from step 1, starting from row 2
  var historySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("History");
  historySheet.insertRowsAfter(1, count);

  // Step 3: Return to sheet called Baylands DM Schedual and copy content including cell color cells A2, B2, and C (count from step 1)
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("A2:C" + (count + 1));
  var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
  var sourceBackgrounds = sourceRange.getBackgrounds();

  // Step 4: Return to sheet called history and paste cells into row 2
  var historyRange = historySheet.getRange("A2:C" + (count + 1));
  historyRange.setValues(sourceValues);
  historyRange.setBackgrounds(sourceBackgrounds);

  // Step 5: Return to sheet called Baylands DM Schedual and sort items in cell range C (count from step 1)
  var sortRange = sourceSheet.getRange("C2:C" + (count + 1));
  var colorSortValues = [];
  var noColorSortValues = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var cellColor = sortRange.getCell(i + 1, 1).getBackground();
    if (cellColor !== "#ffffff") { // Check if cell color is not white (no color)
      colorSortValues.push([i + 1, sortRange.getCell(i + 1, 1).getValue()]);
    } else {
      noColorSortValues.push([i + 1, sortRange.getCell(i + 1, 1).getValue()]);
    }
  }
  if (colorSortValues.length > 0 && noColorSortValues.length > 0) {
    // If there are cells with color and cells without color, sort them accordingly
    colorSortValues.sort(function(a, b) { return a[1] - b[1]; });
    noColorSortValues.sort(function(a, b) { return a[1] - b[1]; });
    var sortedValues = noColorSortValues.concat(colorSortValues);
    var sortedRange = sourceSheet.getRange("C2:C" + (count + 1));
    sortedRange.clearContent();
    for (var j = 0; j < sortedValues.length; j++) {
      sortedRange.getCell(j + 1, 1).setValue(sortedValues[j][1]);
    }
  }

  // Step 6: Clear cells A2 and B2
  sourceSheet.getRange("A2:B2").clear();
}

